# TYPO3 11 felogin with typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

TYPO3 11.5.2

1. I want to display felogin using typoscript with a customized template at position:
   `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.loginBox" />`
2. The original template should be used if felogin is added as a page content element.

The following code works, but changes the view for all felogins:

```
plugin.tx_felogin_login {
  settings.pages = 15
  view {
      templateRootPaths {
        0 = fileadmin/template/current/felogin/Resources/Private/Templates/
        10 = {$plugin.tx_felogin_login.view.templateRootPath}
      }
  }
}
lib.loginBox = USER
lib.loginBox {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = Felogin
  pluginName = Login
}
```

To apply different templates for 1) and 2) I thought the following could work, but it doesn't:

```
lib.loginBox = USER
lib.loginBox {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = Felogin
  pluginName = Login
  settings < plugin.tx_felogin_login.settings
  settings.pages = 15
  view < plugin.tx_felogin_login.view
  view {
      templateRootPaths {
        0 = fileadmin/template/current/felogin/Resources/Private/Templates/
        10 = {$plugin.tx_felogin_login.view.templateRootPath}
      }
  }
}
```

EDIT: the second version does not use the custom template at all and the `settings.pages` = 15 doesn't work => no login possible. With the first version login is working.

Any hints what's wrong with this approach?
How I can achieve different templates for 1) and 2) ?

Edit: Solution as it works for me now:

```
plugin.tx_felogin_login {
  settings.pages = 15
}
lib.loginBox = USER
lib.loginBox {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = Felogin
  pluginName = Login
  view < plugin.tx_felogin_login.view
  view {
      templateRootPaths {
        10 = {$plugin.tx_felogin_login.view.templateRootPath}
        #20 = fileadmin/template/current/felogin/Resources/Private/Templates/
        #should be something like:
        20 = EXT:myfelogin/Resources/Private/Templates/
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is the sorting of your templates!

```
lib.loginBox = USER
lib.loginBox {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = Felogin
  pluginName = Login
  settings < plugin.tx_felogin_login.settings
  settings.pages = 15
  view < plugin.tx_felogin_login.view
  view {
      templateRootPaths {
        10 = {$plugin.tx_felogin_login.view.templateRootPath}
        20 = fileadmin/template/current/felogin/Resources/Private/Templates/
      }
  }
}
```

As `20` is higher than `10`, the template in `fileadmin` will be used.

---

Just as side note: you should always create a site package extension containing all those files and not put them into fileadmin.

Comment: Thank you, the template issue is solved with that. The `settings.pages = 15`  is not working in the second case. I now have a mix, where pages = 15 is set like in my first working attempt, and the templateRootPaths is set like in your code. Do you mind editing your answer accordingly, so that I can mark it as answer which really works? I have edited my question accordingly.
Using site package extension will be my next step, fileadmin/... is still used because I am upgrading from an older Typo3 version to 11.5.

Comment: this seems to be a bug, confirmed and opened https://forge.typo3.org/issues/95914